# [pycharm remote python console]: "cannot connect to X server" error with import pandas

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, ssh, pycharm

I configured a remote python interpreter for PyCharm and connected with SSH credentials. The whole setup works fine, except when I try to import any python library which uses Qt, such as pandas or matplotlib.

I put a screenshot of the remote python console with this error. When I separately ssh into the remote system the same import commands work fine.

[image: please see this screen shot]

I am using Anaconda on the remote server to install all python libraries. I checked the pyqt is installed too.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Maybe your regular ssh session is including X forwarding and the remote python debug session you have set up does not?

Comment: yes I am sure that is happening. I dont know how to do that with PyCharm remote console

Comment: Perhaps you could put it in your ~/.ssh/config for that host?

Comment: what worked is, I installed a GUI in the remote system. Then installed vnc and configured it by running vncserver. Which gives a display number, say 5.0. I then put the environment variable in PyCharm to DISPLAY=:5.0 in the project settings. That worked, and any plot command goes to that display, which I can view with vnc client. 

There is still an error: Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":5.0" But it works. Dont know what I am doing right.

Comment: OK good. Don't worry about the RANDR warning, it is just telling you that VNC does not support the RANDR extension which is used to change resolution or refresh rate on the fly.

Comment: oh i see. ok thanks. I should just mark this as an answer and close i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what worked is, I installed a GUI in the remote system. Then installed vnc and configured it by running vncserver. Which gives a display number, say 5.0. I then put the environment variable in PyCharm to DISPLAY=:5.0 in the project settings. That worked, and any plot command goes to that display, which I can view with vnc client.

There is still an error: Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":5.0" But as mentioned by @Hamish Moffatt, it can be ignored.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand this. I have a similar setup with the same errors as you had. My remote server is a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. So should I install VNC server on that machine?

Comment: again disclaimer, I dont still know what I did right. But answer is yes. It seems like matplotlib needs an environmental variable "DISPLAY" to be set. So if you install VNC server and 'start' it, the variable gets initialized. Then any plot you do in the console of PyCharm gets displayed there.

Comment: Do you start the VNC server within PyCharm on an SSH Terminal?

Comment: You only need to do it once, so it doesnt really matter. I did it on the SSH terminal. I feel like I should also say, that I stopped using PyCharm one month into my project, in favour of simple text editor (sublime) and an ftp editor option (Mobixterm/WinSCP).

Comment: there must be a way to solve this that doesn't involve installing a GUI -- especially given that you don't need to use a GUI to use pandas . . .