# Pycharm - Python Console cannot connect to X server

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

I am essentially running the [same setup as this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838161/pycharm-remote-python-console-cannot-connect-to-x-server-error-with-import) and I am experiencing the same problem in my PyCharm Python Console, i.e. `Backend Qt4Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on. : cannot connect to X server`when I try to import Pandas or Matplotlib.

The only difference is if I run an SSH terminal in PyCharm and run IPython from there then Pandas, Matplotlib, etc all work.

So I think the issue is with some environment variables or paths that are misaligned, any insights as to how I can determine this? Any other fixes?

The version and interpreter of my Pycharm Python Console and the terminal IPython are the same so that isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First you need to build a tunnel with x11forwarding.
   On a Mac type in a terminal `ssh -Y username@host`
2. Then check the display number on the **remote terminal** by typing
   `echo $DISPLAY`
3. Next set the PyCharm remote python console with the following environment variable 
   `DISPLAY=localhost:x.x`